how to float divisions side by side like professional web developers?
I am not getting how to float the second division to the upper right corner of the main division.


html {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.container {
    background-color: #313131;
    width: auto;
    height: calc(100%-30%);
    padding: 20px;
}
.img-wrapper {
    width: 144px;
    height: 216px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.pfmr-info {

    float: right;
}
<div class="container">
 <div class="img-wrapper">
     <picture>
         <source 
         srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1nGd_KYCiywe7k5upLO7OcVJCNtbtwRqB=w2000?authuser=0" media="(orientation: portrait)" />
         <img 
         src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1nGd_KYCiywe7k5upLO7OcVJCNtbtwRqB=w2000?authuser=0" alt="Cherie Deville" />
       </picture>
 </div>
 <div class="pfmr-info">
     <span style="color: #848484;font-size: medium;">Cherie Deville</span>
 </div>
</div>



I need the second div to move to the upper-right corner but it just moves to the right. What should I do?

Professional Web Developers will not misuse tools as outdated hacks. They will use the correct tools such as Flexbox. float is for floating elements within flow text. It is not a tool to align elements next to each other. PS What is the main div? Add a drawing of the intended layout.

float shouldn't be used in that situation. Instead, you can apply display: flex to your .container to place the children of that element side by side.
One of the default settings for flex is justify-content: flex-start, which (judging from your description) is most likely what you want. Otherwise you could add that parameter and change its setting.
Also align-items is a setting you might wat to change from its default normal to baseline or center (just try that to see the effects).
Additionally, you might want to add some margin-left to .pfmr-info to create a little distance between the image and the name. (see my example below)


html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.container {
  background-color: #313131;
  width: auto;
  height: calc(100%-30%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrapper {
  width: 144px;
  height: 216px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pfmr-info {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <picture>
      <source srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1nGd_KYCiywe7k5upLO7OcVJCNtbtwRqB=w2000?authuser=0" media="(orientation: portrait)" />
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1nGd_KYCiywe7k5upLO7OcVJCNtbtwRqB=w2000?authuser=0" alt="Cherie Deville" />
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div class="pfmr-info">
    <span style="color: #848484;font-size: medium;">Cherie Deville</span>
  </div>
</div>




    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Your Project</title>
        <style>
    
          * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          }
    
          body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
            background-color: #1b1b1b;
          }
    
          .container {
            background-color: #313131;
            width: auto;
            height: calc(100%-30%);
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
          }
    
          .content {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
          }
    
          .img-wrapper {
            width: 144px;
            height: 216px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
          }
    
          img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
          }
    
          .id {
            padding-right: 20px;
            color: #848484;
            font-size: medium;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

    <div class="container">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <picture>
                <source
                  srcset="
                    https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1nGd_KYCiywe7k5upLO7OcVJCNtbtwRqB=w2000?authuser=0
                  "
                  media="(orientation: portrait)"
                />
                <img
                  src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1nGd_KYCiywe7k5upLO7OcVJCNtbtwRqB=w2000?authuser=0"
                  alt="Cherie Deville"
                />
              </picture>
            </div>
            <p class="id">Cherie Deville</p>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
      </body>
    </html>


Always explain your answer. Never just dump a block of code and expect everyone to understand what you did

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
